# Perl 5.8 cascading null checks

Tags: perl, groovy, null

Let's say I have the following Groovy code:

```
String name = child.getParent()?.getParent()?.getName();
```

Note that `getParent()` may return `null`, and in this case the code continues to work without null pointer exceptions being thrown.

Is there a way to do this clearly in one line in Perl 5.8? I am open to writing a generic helper method to accomplish this.

I'm running into situations where I have several nested objects and am having to do something like:

```
my $name = $child && $child->getParent && $child->getParent->getParent && $child->getParent->getParent->getName;
```

Yes this is in one line, but is fugly IMO.

Comment: Related: [How do I handle errors in methods chains in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064975/how-do-i-handle-errors-in-methods-chains-in-perl)

Comment: This is where a query language (such as XPath or CSS selector) would be useful.

Comment: It isn't clear whether you need to implement this Groovy code in Perl, or if you've just found another way to snipe at Perl. Are you being serious?

Comment: @Borodin - Yes I am serious, my team owns a large existing code base in perl.

Comment: @lots_of_questions: Okay, so where does Groovy fit in?

Comment: @Borodin, groovy fits in because I am aware it has this feature. I was simply wondering if there was an equivalent in perl which had the same level of compactness.

Comment: I'll point out - Perl 5.8 was released in 2003, and was end of life in 2008. It may be worth considering moving to a _slightly_ newer release.

Answer (score 3):

In *my* opinion, your original Groovy code is on the boundary of readability anyway. I would implement it rather differently, but a similar expression in Perl would be

```
my $name = (
    $node = $node->get_parent or
    $node = $node->get_parent or
    $node->get_name
);
```

The utility of a language isn't defined by its ability to represent complex constructs in very few characters

Comment: for the sake of readability: in groovy one would write `child.parent?.parent?.name` OPs code is verbose/javaish.

Answer (score 0):

probably a bit evil is using eval:

```
my $name = eval { $child->getParent->getParent->getName }
```

an alternative is to make use of `last` which can be used to leave a block (i.e. a standalone `{...}` is similar to `for(1) {...}`):

```
my $name; { $name = (($child->getParent || last)->getParent || last)->getName }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to extract information from the DOM of a HTML page. For this I recommend that you use a Perl module that just does that. Have a look at [Mojo::DOM](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM)